# What is the use of resumePath in PingFederate

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml-2.0, pingfederate

Can somebody please explain the purpose of resumepath/resumeurl in PingFederate and how can we leverage that while developing custom IdP Adapter for 2FA flow?

If we want to invoke same IdP adapter multiple times during a single transaction then can we use resumePath for that while developing the IdP adapter and how?

Answer (score 0):

Resumepath is needed to point back to PingFederate to complete the authentication request. That URL is a resume path for PingFederate to complete the authentication request. It is part of the authentication flow. Once the authentication request completes and is successful PingFederate will then redirect to the redirect URI of the client and that can be whatever you want but it does need to be defined ahead of time.

Comment: This is mostly correct. The resume URL is how the user is moved to "the next step" in the authentication policy. OP cannot use it multiple time inside a singular step of the policy - the processing needs to be done at one time upon redirection to the adapter that has been built.